# Disable MySQL updates on Ubuntu 18.0

Tags: apt, mysql

I have a specific MySQL version installed and want to disable any updates as a recent update seems to have messed up my existing config files.

When I run apt-get update I do see errors so I think the signature failed.

```
W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm just not sure how to remove updates but keep mysql installed.

[edit]

Apparently I did have it already on hold, but not all of the packages...

```
mysql-apt-config                                install
mysql-client-5.7                                install
mysql-client-core-5.7                           install
mysql-common                                    install
mysql-server                                    hold
mysql-server-5.7                                install
mysql-server-core-5.7                           install
```

Comment: That's not an error (E:). It's a warning (W:). EXPKEYSIG means Expired Key. Update the key using apt-key. To disable updates: `sudo apt-mark hold  <package_name>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: Ok, I already had mysql-server on hold (duh) but now see the other packages so one of them must have updated to cause me grief.   (list edited above)